# Using an rct bridge in iOS app to represent table view in react native

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to table view in react using an existing iOS sdk. i.e I will need to use the RCT bridge (via RCT_EXPORT function) to do this. This is the first time I am using this bridge header, could anyone please tell me how i can do this, below is how the code looks:

viewcontroller.m

```
RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)
{
   MyProduct *product = self.products[indexPath.row];
   NSLog(@"products list is gonna be sent now");
   callback(@[product.title]);

}
```

How can i display the data i return from the above function in a react js table view?

**Note(below is the function that i am trying to export) **

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  MyProduct *product = self.products[indexPath.row];

  cell.textLabel.text = product.title;

  return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a component for this. Please check this out: [aksonov/react-native-tableview](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tableview)